# Убирание свойства cheked при повторном нажатии на радиокнопку

Tags: jquery

Подскажите пожалста, как сделать так, чтобы кликая повторно на выбранную радио кнопку, она снова становилась не cheked.
Я так понимаю, я где-то ошибся в коде

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
$('input[type="radio"]').click(function(){
   var ir = $(this).prop("checked")
   if(ir){
       $(this).removeAttr("checked")
   }
})
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="check1" type="radio" name="group1" value="val1" checked>
<label for="check1">Text1</label>
<input id="check2" type="radio" name="group2" value="val2">
<label for="check2">Text2</label>
<input id="check3" type="radio" name="group3" value="val3">
<label for="check3">Text3</label>
```

Comment: Ну cheked != checked =) Но работает это только 1 раз

Comment: да в том то и проблема)

Comment: Ну в целом для данной цели существуют checkbox , но если надо пилить так, то наверно стоит добавить логику на добавление checked т.к. ты сразу его сносишь по клику (дефолтное значение срабатывает до твоего обработчика)

Comment: что-то я завис совсем, подскажите

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('input[type="radio"]').click(function(){
    $(this).attr('checked', function(index, attr){
      return attr ? null : 'checked';
    });
  })
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="check1" type="radio" name="group1" value="val1">
<label for="check1">Text1</label>
<input id="check2" type="radio" name="group2" value="val2">
<label for="check2">Text2</label>
<input id="check3" type="radio" name="group3" value="val3" cheked>
<label for="check3">Text3</label>
```